# Stop SSRS adding Excel "Outline" when exporting to Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

We have a report which looks like this:

[image]

If I then go *Actions>Export>Excel* I get the following:

[image]

Unfortunately the number circled is misleading. This column is a count of users - so if the same user was in several months they should only be counted in the total as 1.

I assume out-of-the-box it adds the excel outline whenever we include the expansion/collapse (+/-) functionality in the report.

Is there a way in the `rdl` file to stop `RS`'s export functionality of adding the outline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Outline behaviour in Excel is triggered by the ToggleItem property in SSRS.  You cannot set this with an Expression.  Therefore I would remove the ToggleItem property from all textboxes.

Instead I would use Bookmarks and/or DocumentMap functionality - these achieve similar results and generally work better across a broad range of rendered output formats.

Comment: +1 thanks Mike. We knew what caused the behaviour and have already disabled the (+/-) therefore disabling the Outline. What I would like though is to be able to leave the (+/-) in the Report but when exported to Excel not have an Outline - can this be achieved via some modification to the actual rdl code?

Comment: I'm not a fan of hacking at RDL code, but I imagine you would need to remove the ToggleItem tag.

Comment: But the point is Mike - I don't want to lose the toggle item in the actual ssrs report - just want to lose the outline in the excel that is created.